# How to disable IBM Websphere Commerce Developer Feature Pack 4.0.0.0

Tags: websphere-commerce

While disabling IBM web commerce,I am always getting bellow error message.
"

> C:\WCDE_ENT70\bin>disableFeature.bat -DfeatureName=foundation
>   Disabling components
>
> The system cannot find the path specified.
>
> disableFeature.bat FAILED. The log file will contain more details
>   about the failure. See C:\WCDE_E~3\logs\d isableFeature.log
>   Troubleshooting help is available in the WebSphere Commerce
>   Information Center
>   http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.commerce.in
>   stall.doc/refs/rigtrbshootmain.htm

"

Log file was not generated.

May I know how to disable the IBM Websphere Commerce Developer Feature Pack 4.0.0.0.?

I noticed that I could see same error message if I run versionInfo.bat as well.

Should I need to update any environmental variables?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Opening a support ticket is the quickest way to get help on such errors.

But, if some one is seeing the mentioned error and are up for some investigation (aren't we all :-)) :

Key error that catches my eye is this one:

> "The system cannot find the path specified"

Since you don't see the log file, I guess utility could not get far enough to even create the log file - likely because one or more of the paths it expects does not exist.

I would check `C:\WCDE_ENT70\bin\setenv.bat` file for the various paths set there. One or more of those paths may be the issue.

If paths exists, other thing I would check is : Windows uses the "8.3" short file names, so when looking for folders check for their short names and collisions on those names. Since we expect Windows to make OP's path as `C:\IBM\WCDE_E~1`, removing any other entries that has the same first six characters is worth a shot.

Else - PMR :-)

Answer (score -1):

I would open a ticket with IBM Software Support.

-- Long Answer
Seems like a bigger issue if logs are not being generated correctly hence the ticket with IBM Software Support.